# Problem while printing string using Pointers in C Programming

Tags: c, pointers

Respected Experts ,

I am a newbie to C programming Language .

I am trying to print a string in C Language . The code runs successfully but when i
enter the string , it does not displays the string entered by the user in return

I have attached the screenshot of the code which I am trying to execute .

Please help me out .

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[20];
    char *pt;

    printf("Enter any string :\n");
    gets(str);
    pt=&str[0];

    for(*pt=0; *pt != '\0'; *pt++)
    {
        printf("%c", *pt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post code as image.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text but post text as text. Take the [tour] and read this: [ask] ans this: [mcve]

Comment: `for (*pt=0 ; *pt != '\0' ; *pt++)` --> `for ( ; pt; pt++)`. Also, use [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead of `gets`, which is a security vulnerability.

Comment: See [Why is the `gets()` function too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

Answer (score 2):

The initialization `*pt = 0;` is causing the continuation test `*pt != 0` to fail immediately, so your loop stops before printing anything.

You already initialized `pt` before the loop, so you don't need that step in the `for()` header. And you should be incrementing the pointer, not the character that it points so, so the update should be `pt++`.

```
for (; *pt != '\0'; pt++) {
    printf("%c", *pt);
}
```

BTW, `ptr = &str[0];` can be simplified to just `ptr = str;`. It's also more idiomatic to put this in the `for` header, so it would be:

```
for (pt = str; *pt != '\0'; pt++)
```

Answer (score 1):

First - **NEVER NEVER NEVER** use `gets`, not even in toy code.  It was deprecated in the 1999 standard and has been removed from the standard library as of the 2011 standard.  It *will* introduce a point of failure / major security hole in your code.  Use `fgets` instead, just be aware it will store the newline to your buffer if there's room.

Restructure your `for` statement as follows:

```
for ( pt = str; *pt != '\0'; pt++ )
```

The first expression sets `pt` to point to the first character in `str` (in this context, `str` is equivalent to `&str[0]`).  The second compares the *value* of the element that `pt` points to against the string terminator.  Since you are trying to check the value of the pointed-to object, you must use the `*` operator to deference `pt`.  The final expression advances `pt` to point to the next character in the string.

Finally, is there a reason you're printing the string out character by character instead of just writing `printf( "%s\n", str );` ?